# GTK+ MenuItem Size Small

Tags: menuitem, font-size, gtk3

On a machine running Windows, the MenuItems are too small for my use case.

Therefore, my question is, "*how I may increase the font size of the text "Save", "Load" and "Exit?"* "

If not, then *how can I increase the padding between the MenuItems?*
(without adding more of those line separators as seen between "Load" and "Exit")

Additionally, how may I remove the intermediate variable *SubMenu1*, if possible?

Cropped Screenshot

[image: Cropper Screenshot]

Below is a complete source to reproduce:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);


    GtkWidget* Window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    GtkWidget* MenuBar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
    GtkWidget* MenuItem_File = gtk_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic("_File");

    GtkWidget* SubMenu1 = gtk_menu_new();

    GtkWidget* Item_Save = gtk_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic("_Save");
    GtkWidget* Item_Load = gtk_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic("_Load");
    GtkWidget* Item_Exit = gtk_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic("_Exit");


    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(SubMenu1), Item_Save);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(SubMenu1), Item_Load);

    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(SubMenu1), gtk_separator_menu_item_new());

    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(SubMenu1), Item_Exit);


    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(MenuItem_File), SubMenu1);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(MenuBar), MenuItem_File);


    GtkWidget* VerticalBox;

    VerticalBox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(VerticalBox), MenuBar, false, false, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Window), VerticalBox);


    gtk_widget_show_all(MenuBar);
    gtk_widget_show(VerticalBox);


    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(Window), 950, 600);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(Window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(Window), "My Title");

    gtk_widget_show(Window);


    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gtk3's font size control (and other style properties) are delegated to the CSS files. It is generally discouraged to do this in your program (though this is certainly possible - have a look at Gtk3's CSS_provider functions). But normally you would like your program to look 'compatible' with other programs, I suspect.

The reason is that the aspect of your program should be controllable from the outside - be it for reasons of personal taste, or for accessibility. So, if you consider the font style for the menus etc, too small, you can:

- Choose another 'theme' or style, eg. on the [Gnome-Look site](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/ord/latest/)
- Look at the Window manager's preferences for an 'Appearance' setting  (as it is called in XFCE. There are similar tools in Gnome, KDE, etc.)
- Modify the CSS files of the theme you are currently using

Many other visual aspects are controlled from the CSS files: Separation between elements (eg. menuitems), rounding of corners, visual effects, etc etc... but, thanks to the CSS system, you can normally just 'tweak' the items you like.

**EDIT:** If you want to run the executable on another machine, you'd probably need a window manager to run it under, which makes the above still valid.

There is still another solution (which I mentioned above, first paragraph), which is to change the CSS temporarily using the [CSS provider set of Gtk functions](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/CssProvider.html). If you *really* want to code program rigidly, you can use the `modify_font` method of GtkWidget.