# How to increase the font-size of a button or label in a gtk3 program in C?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

Is there any way to increase the font-size of a button or label in a gtk3 program in C programming language without changing the font family?

I know that I can use such a style:

```
    style "labels" = "widgets" {
    font_name = "Sans Bold 14"
    }
```

But is there any way to change only the font size?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS styles in GTK+, with the font size being set with:

```
* {
  font-size: 14;
}
```

You can read more on GTK+ CSS styles in their [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html), but note that there was a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41132460/3488231) in earlier versions of GTK+ which may cause this not to work.

Comment: it is currently recommended to use pixels ; *{font-size: 14px;}